# Play video using AVPlayer

Tags: iphone, ios, avplayer

I am getting frame buffer one by one from video file using `AVAssetReader` and doing some operation on the frame  and then saving new frame to temp file using `AVAssetWritter`.Now I have temp file path where all new frame is saving one by one.
Is there any way to play video at the time frames is continuously adding to temp file??

here is code to play video from temp path(where frames is continuously adding)

```
- (void)loadAssetFromFile {

    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[(mMediaReader.mCameraRecorder) tempVideoFilePath ]] options:nil];
    NSString *tracksKey = @"tracks";

    [asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:tracksKey] completionHandler:
     ^{

         // Completion handler block.
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                        ^{
                            NSError *error = nil;
                            AVKeyValueStatus status = [asset statusOfValueForKey:tracksKey error:&error];

                            if (status == AVKeyValueStatusLoaded) {
                                self.mPlayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
                                [mPlayerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"
                                                options:0 context:&ItemStatusContext];
                                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                                                           object:mPlayerItem];
                               self.mPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:mPlayerItem];
                                [mPlayerView setPlayer:mPlayer];
                                [self play:nil];
                            }
                            else {
                                // You should deal with the error appropriately.
                                NSLog(@"The asset's tracks were not loaded:\n%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                            }
                        });
     }];
}

- (IBAction)play:sender {
    [mPlayer play];
}
```

And code inside the block never runs.

Comment: looking for your suggestion ??

Comment: still looking solution for this

Comment: It looks like `loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:completionHandler:` is a method on `AVMetaDataItem`, not `AVURLAsset` or `AVAsset`.  Can you confirm that the `NSURL` object is not `nil`?

Comment: Correction: `loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:completionHandler:` is a method required by the `AVAsynchronousKeyValueLoading` protocol, which `AVAsset` conforms to.

Comment: @sho It is not nil. Is something wrong in code ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dividing the video in multiple sub videos worked for me.

What I did instead of saving full video in one temp path. I divided that video in multiple sub videos and then replaced `AVPlayerItem` property of `AVPlayer` accordingly.

So now functionality is working same as video streaming . :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also convert the CMSampleBuffer that the AVAssetReader returns into a CGImage and then a UIImage and display that in a UIImageView, to render the frames as they are pulled out of the original video file.

There is example code inside the [AVFoundation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/05_MediaRepresentations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH2-SW4) that shows how to do this conversion.